# Getting a laravel post api to recognize json data

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

Making an API, I encountered an issue I'm not too sure about. I am trying to input a block of JSON Data because this is what the node client would give the API.

I'm getting the error:

```
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I have tried doing json_encode on the $data variable, and have also tried this:

```
$data = json_encode(json_encode($validatedData["required_data"]), true);
```

but with no luck.

I currently have this code:

```
    public function putData(Request $request) {
        if($request->get('token') !== config()->get('discord.CLIENT_SECRET'))
            return response()->json($this->badAuthResponse);
        $guilds = Guilds::all();
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
           "required_data" => "required"
        ]);
        $data = $validatedData["required_data"];
        foreach($data as $guild) {
           //complete the task of whatever im going to do with guild in a bit
        }
    }
```

and im trying to pass this data:

```
{
   "1":{
      "is_setup":1,
      "guild_data":{
         "prefix":"m>",
         "locale":"en",
         "filter":false
      }
   },
   "2":{
      "warn_data":{
         "1":{
            "total_count":1,
            "reasons":{
               "1":"phising links"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "3":{

   }
}
```

Comment: i dont see an required_data in your posted sample data. Do you want the validation to fail and its not failing?

Comment: The required_data is the name of the data passed through, testing it in postman. The passing of the data is correct, but I'm trying to change it from a string to a JSON object.

Comment: have you tried dd $data and what was it?

Comment: Dumping the $data variable gave me the JSON I provided but it was stringified, and trying to encode or decode it gave no help.

Comment: It should be $data = json_decode($validatedData["required_data"]), true);

Comment: I've tried that, I dumped $data trying json_decode and it was null.

Comment: Can you show me the stringified json of data?

Comment: Its in the question, just all the newlines are \n

Comment: Stranged, I decoded it and it show an array ... http://prntscr.com/se7v7g

Comment: Very strange, could it be because of the laravel validation?

Comment: So you use the return value from validate? Would be the problem because it will not return the orginal but return an Object.. just decode it and check by isset().

Comment: Uhm, I did what you suggested and still get null when dumping $data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some strange reason, it did not work with the name

```
required_data
```

but on changing it to just

```
data
```

it  suddenly started to work, not sure why.

```
    public function putData(Request $request) {
        if($request->get('token') !== config()->get('discord.CLIENT_SECRET'))
            return response()->json($this->badAuthResponse);
        $guilds = Guilds::all();
        $validData = $request->validate([
           "data" => "required"
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($validData["data"], true);
        foreach($data as $guild=>$data) {
            print_r(($guild));
        }
    }
```